# Javascript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined(…)

Tags: javascript

Hello I have the following code:

I want to be able to change the background color of the inputs when they are clicked. As well as do other things.

```js
     

    var bp = false;
     var np = false;
     var b = false;
     var i = false;
     var u = false;
    
    function iFrameOn(){
        richTextField.document.designMode = 'On';
    }
    function iBold(){
      richTextField.document.execCommand('Bold',false,null);
      if(b == false){
       b = true;
       document.getElementById['btn1'].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      }else if(b == true){
       b = false;
       document.getElementById['btn1'].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      }
    }
```

```html
<center> 
              <div>
                <input class="buttonOnBar" id="btn1" type="button" value="" onClick="javascript:iBold();" style="background-image: url('img/icons/bold.png');" title="Bold text">
                <input class="buttonOnBar" id="btn2" type="button" value="" onClick="javascript:iUnderline();" style="background-image: url('img/icons/underline.png');"title="Underlined text">
                <input class="buttonOnBar" id="btn3" type="button" value="" onClick="javascript:iItalic();" style="background-image: url('img/icons/italic.png');"title="Italic text">
                <input class="buttonOnBar" id="btn4" type="button" value="" onClick="javascript:iUnorderedList();" style="background-image: url('img/icons/numberPoint.png');"title="Numbered list">
                <input class="buttonOnBar" id="btn5" type="button" value="" onClick="javascript:iOrderedList();" style="background-image: url('img/icons/bulletPoint.png');"title="Bullet point list">
                <input class="buttonOnBar" id="btn6" type="button" value="" onClick="javascript:iLink();" style="background-image: url('img/icons/link.png');"title="Insert link">
                <input class="buttonOnBar" id="btn7" type="button" value="" onClick="javascript:iImage();" style="background-image: url('img/icons/picture.png');"title="Insert image">
              </div>
            </center>

              <textarea style="display:none;"id="postTextStyle" name="Text" cols="100" rows="14"></textarea>
              <center><iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField" style="border:#000000 1px solid; width:700px;height:300px;"></iframe></center>

              <textarea id="postTagStyle" name="desc" rows="2" maxlength = "1000" placeholder="Description"></textarea>

              <center><input type="button" value="Post"  style="margin-top:40px;"class = "Post2" onClick="javascript:submit_form();"></center>
           
           </form>
          
          <br>
          <script type="text/javascript"src="WYSIWYG.js"></script>
```

For whatever reason i keep getting the error that is in the title when i click the input button. Why do I get this error and why doesn't the color change?

Comment: use  `document.getElementById('btn1')` instead of  `document.getElementById['btn1']`. And make sure You have an element with Id "btn1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean

```
document.getElementById('btn1').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```